Qiskit Statevector for simple circuit does not match the expected answer
I'm looking at a simple circuit in qiskit and observe a state vector that is different from what I would expect.
Specifically, I start with $|0>\otimes |0>$, apply X gate to the first qubit and look at the state.
I would expect this to result into the state vector as follows:
$$|00>\rightarrow |10> = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\\end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \\\end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\\0\\  \end{matrix} \right) $$
Instead I get [0,1,0,0] from qiskit.
Here is the code:

from qiskit import QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
import numpy as np
qr = QuantumRegister(2, 'qReg')
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr)
qc.x(qr[0])
np.array(Statevector(qc))

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thank you very much

The issue is that Qiskit uses reverse bit ordering. Link.

It is correct that you are assuming the wrong qubit ordering, but it has nothing to do with Qiskit using “reverse bit ordering”. Qiskit uses a standard way of ordering qubits, with the least significant qubit to the right and the most significant to the left: $q_n \dots q_2 q_1 q_0$ (just like you write down binary or even decimal numbers). The issue is that in programming it is common to assume that the 0th element of a list (or a string) is the element most to the left, which is opposite to how we order numbers.
